# How to create a new column in R that counts unique values

Tags: r, count, unique

I am quite new to R and I am mainly learning by visiting these Q&A sites. I initially wanted to post a comment on a previous question, that partially answerd my question, but was unable to beacause of my reputation, as I just became a member.

Link to question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16160671/4681908

What I want to do is to create a new column that counts the unique values for a varialbe in my dataset for unique IDs. Instead of getting a list as the following code:

```
with(mydf, tapply(Spp, Cnty, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

,I would like to code it to a new variable. Could anyone help me with this? I am sorry for any lack of information, and thank you in advance

Comment: Use `ave` and convert `Spp` to a `character` as in `with(mydf, ave(as.character(Spp), Cnty, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg But, this will return a character output.  As the `Spp` is already a factor, it is better to convert to `numeric` to return numeric values

Comment: @arkrun, yeah  `as.numeric` could be used too. I just wanted to illustrate one possibility. Though it seems you also added this. I'm sure this is a some type of a dupe that should be closed anyway.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It could be a dupe, I haven't searched for any.  If you find it, close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `n_distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(Cnty) %>% mutate(Count=n_distinct(Spp))
```

Or `uniqueN` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(mydf)[,Count:=uniqueN(Spp) ,by = Cnty][]
```

Or use `ave` instead of `tapply`. As 'Spp' is a 'factor' column, you can use 'as.numeric'

```
mydf$Count <-  with(mydf, ave(as.numeric(Spp), Cnty,
                      FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Comment: mydf$Count <-  with(mydf, ave(as.numeric(Spp), Cnty, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))

Worked perfectly. Thank you so much